# DBSCAN python with periodic boundary conditions

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I'm trying to use sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN for analysis of clusters in a 2D grid.
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN
But I have encountered the problem, that clustering across periodic boundary conditions is not implemented.

Does anyone know an implementation that takes periodic boundary conditions into account? or how to implement it?

/ Mikkel C

Answer (score 1):

DBSCAN does not need to be modified for this.

Just roll your own distance function, instead of using Euclidean distance.

There you can easily implement your periodic boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra dimension to enforce periodic boundary conditions.  Say I wanted to use DBSCAN to extract points by their angle (theta) in polar coordinates.  If I run DBSCAN on [theta], points 1 degree and 359 degrees would not be clustered together.  However if I run DBSCAN on [sin(theta), cos(theta)], this solves the issue.

Comment: ... but it may well further distort your data.